# How to make text vertical in a jQuery UI Layout toggler?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-layout

I am using the jquery-ui-layout plugin in a website: [jQuery UI Layout Hompage](http://layout.jquery-dev.com/)

There are options `togglerContent_open` and `togglerContent_closed` that allow you to place html inside of the toggler. I want to include text in my EAST pane, but my problem is the text displays horizontally across a vertical toggler, so only the first character can be seen.

[image: toggler bad]

How can I display it so that it reads vertically instead? Like either of (sry, very rough mock-up) the options below. Is it an option in jQuery UI Layout or just css?

[image: toggler desired]

**EDIT: Does anyone know if this is possible by modifying jQuery UI Layout settings?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.parentPane {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.parentPane > div {
    display:inline-block;
    height:100px;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align:center;
}

.eastPane {
    background-color:#CA7DBD;
    width: 49.5%;
}

.westPane {
    background-color:#4679BD;
    width: 49.5%;
}

.rotator {
    background-color:#ccc;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position:relative;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.wizard1 {
    left:0;
}
.wizard2 {
    right:40px;
    ;
}
.wizard2 {
    right:40px;
    ;
}
.wizard3 {
    right:80px;
    ;
}
.wizard4 {
    right:120px;
    ;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentPane">
    <div class="eastPane">East Pane</div>
    <div class="westPane"><div>West Pane</div>
        <div class="rotator wizard1">Wizard 1</div>
        <div class="rotator wizard2">Wizard 2</div>
        <div class="rotator wizard3">Wizard 3</div>
        <div class="rotator wizard4">Wizard 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can make use of CSS3 `transform` property. This would rotate the text, however the alignment wouldn't still various such container's (`div's` or `span's`) apart. Hence, you would use `relative positioning` to align them next to each other. This is the general syntax you would use of `rotation`.

```
transform: rotate(90deg);
```

Making use of the relative positioning , you can define the distance between multiple content (where the text is vertical).

See the below snippet

```css
.rotator {
    background-color:#ccc;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position:relative;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.wizard1 {
     left:0;
}

.wizard2 {
     right:40px;;
}

.wizard2 {
     right:40px;;
}

.wizard3 {
     right:80px;;
}

.wizard4 {
     right:120px;;
}
```

```html
<div class="rotator wizard1">Wizard 1</div>
<div class="rotator wizard2">Wizard 2</div>
<div class="rotator wizard3">Wizard 3</div>
<div class="rotator wizard4">Wizard 4</div>
```

Hope this helps!!!